# Meaning of 'sign' in Writhe Matrix

Tags: mobile-robot, control, robotic-arm, wheeled-robot, motion-planning

Following is the equation of Writhe matrix from the article [Topology based Representation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiShMzIuOnLAhVIQyYKHS5RD-oQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de%2Fmlr%2Fpapers%2F13-ivan-IJRR.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHftBdmoPCF6xDv59fxlEfwGkLGvg&sig2=m9a-rNtK1v6NAJxqr3rTqA&bvm=bv.117868183,bs.1,d.eWE)(page no. 6).
[image]

What is the meaning of 'sign' in the second part of this equation? I am not sure if this is some typo in that article as the other article of [Hierarchical Motion Planning](http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/rss08/p59.pdf)(page no. 3), compleletely neglects the term 'sign[...]'
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign is a function that returns +1 whenever the operand is anything positive, -1 if it's anything negative, and 0 if it's zero. I'm not sure if it's mathematically correct for your equation as I'm not familiar with it, but it's not an uncommon function, especially in the realm of robotics.

Comment: Plus the sign of a vector is generally returned as a vector where each element is the sign as @Chuck describes for the corresponding element of its argument.

Comment: @SteveO is correct; there's no definition for multiple elements (what would it be if a11 were positive and a21 were negative?) so any multidimensional inputs yield multidimensional outputs.